# How to convert nlme summary object into table

Tags: r, kable, gtsummary, flextable, nlme

I have the following dataset

```
df3 = structure(list(A = c("51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57"), B = c(84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5), 
    C = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0"), D = c(73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
    72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
    72, 72, 72, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 
    74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 
    74, 74, 74), E = c(136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815)), row.names = c(NA, -180L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

on which I have run the following code to get the mixed model

```
obj = (nlme::lme(E ~ B + C + D, random = ~1|A, df3) %>% 
      summary())$tTable 

flextable(obj)
```

however I am not able to get the table in which showing the results. Has anyone any idea to get the table with any package that you you (flextable, gtsummary, kableExtra and so on)?
Of course I would like to get all the columns (including variable names)

```
                   Value  Std.Error   DF     t-value      p-value
(Intercept) -12.68019966 3.10808245 1827  -4.0797501 4.702378e-05
B            -0.24611480 0.02288007   59 -10.7567325 1.557930e-15
C1            0.36800234 3.57315266   59   0.1029909 9.183194e-01
D             0.08818415 0.02749166   59   3.2076696 2.163542e-03
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With flextable, you can use `as_flextable()` to convert models into tables.

```
library(flextable)

obj <- nlme::lme(E ~ B + C + D, random = ~1|A, df3)
as_flextable(obj)
```

[image]

With the dev version, there is support for `options(show.signif.stars = FALSE)`.

[image]

If you don't want to keep the footer part, just drop it with `delete_part()`

```
as_flextable(obj) |> delete_part(part = "footer")
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work even in case I would like to get rid of the random effect part? I am trying extracting  the reating element but in this case it does not seem to work

Comment: no, but I can add an argument for that in the dev version, I'll let you know here when it will be available. In that case it will be the same or very close to the solution given by @daveasmstrong

Comment: @12666727b9 it's available in the dev version, you can use `as_flextable(obj, add.random = FALSE) |> delete_part(part = "footer")` to get what you want, hope it will be useful

Comment: Thank you so much. Just for curiosity..is that the default font that you have used for this example? Or if you have used another one, which was that?

Comment: It's helvetica, See https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/blob/master/R/defaults.R#L1 for initial values. I highly recommend to use `gdtools::register_gfont()` with a google font of your choice and then to set it by default with `flextable::set_flextable_defaults(font.family = "...")`

Answer (score 2):

If you turn the `summary()$tTable` into a data frame (or tibble)

```r
df3 = structure(list(A = c("51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57"), B = c(84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5), 
    C = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0"), D = c(73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
    72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
    72, 72, 72, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 
    74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 
    74, 74, 74), E = c(136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815)), row.names = c(NA, -180L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```r
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
mod <- nlme::lme(E ~ B + C + D, random = ~1|A, df3)
summary(mod)$tTable %>% as_tibble(rownames="variable") %>% knitr::kable(digits=3)
```

| variable | Value | Std.Error | DF | t-value | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 93.900 | 0.382 | 174 | 245.532 | 0 |
| B | 0.697 | 0.006 | 2 | 123.619 | 0 |
| C1 | -75.549 | 0.633 | 2 | -119.272 | 0 |
| D | -1.499 | 0.006 | 2 | -268.038 | 0 |

<sup>Created on 2023-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>